# How to name an anonymous function or a express middleware in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Here's the middleware that I use in express:

```
    const app = express();
    const port = 8000;
    const f = () => {
        return async (req, res, next) => {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            return next();
        }
    }
    const namedFunction = f();
    app.use(namedFunction); // earlier I was using `app.use(f());`
```

But my function still appear as anonymous function in profiler:
Something like this:

[image]

A bit of background:
We want to see which middleware is causing the high latency, but because the middlewares are anonymous, we can't narrow down the cause in our APM + JS profiler. The preceding is just one example; we use approximately 40 middleware packages over which we have no control.

That's why I thought passing `f()` to `namedFunction` should fix the issue but it wasn't so looking for help on this.

**Other tries till now**:
As per Jonsharpe's comment I tried:

```
app.use(function namedFunction() { f()(...arguments) });
```

But in profiler it still appear as an anonymous function

Comment: could be the callback function youre returning

Comment: If you want it to have a name why not make it _not_ an anonymous function? Write a vanilla function (`return async function <name>() { ...`) rather than an arrow function.

Comment: Updated my Question @jonrsharpe hope my ask is clear now. I don't have a control over f() content so that's why tried using namedFunction but it didn't work

Comment: Write a proxy function, maybe: `app.use(function namedFunction() { f()(...arguments) });`? Or rename it as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871040/3001761.

Comment: Giving it a try, probably should work but could JS profiler still takes up f()(...arguments) as an anonymous function

Comment: @jonrsharpe it still appears as an anonymous one in the profiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot many tries of assigning name, refactoring use I came up with this and finally the profiler was able to point out that it's the wrappedFunction which is causing it so going ahead I'll need to create a wrapperFunction for each of the case.

Here's a sample of what worked in the end:

```
const f = () => {
        return async (req, res, next) => {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            return next();
        }
    }
    const wrappedFunction  = async(req, res, next) => {
        await new Promise(resolve => f()(req, res, resolve)); // Now since time is spent in this block that's why profiler is picking this up instead of the anonymous function as the main resource consuming function
        next();
    }
    
    app.use(wrappedFunction);
```

And here's what it looks like in profiler now:

[image]

**Just an note** to others who might not know the context:
By default the official middlewares are usually named functions but some 3rd party middleware return an anonymous function which profiler/APM isn't able to pick up and point to code block from there.
That's why it's important to have a named function instead of `anonymous middleware` showing up in UI and being unclear where to look at.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know much about `express`, I can at least clear up a misconception you have about anonymous functions.

When you create a function and immediately store it in a variable, the interpreter can implicitly use the name of the variable as the name of the function. That is true of both functions created with the `function` expression or with the arrow notation.

```
const foo = () => {};
foo.name; // "foo";

const bar = function () {};
bar.name; // "bar";
```

But if you create a function and then immediately pass it as an argument or return it, the interpreter cannot give it a name at creation, so it becomes anonymous.

So when you did this:

```
const namedFunction = f();
```

All you did was store the already-created anonymous function returned by `f()` inside the variable `namedFunction`. You did not actually give it a name. To do that, you would need to do something like so:

```
const unnamedFunction = f();
const namedFunction = (...args) => unnamedFunction(...args);
```

Which simply wraps the unnamed function into a named one.

You could also create a variable to store an arrow function before returning it or passing it as a callback.

```
const meaningfulName = () => { ... };
return meaningfulName;
```

But unless you actually rely on the behavior of arrow functions, I would just use a named function expression in those cases:

```
return function meaningfulName () { ... };
```

Comment: A very good explanation of why this happens, which is, IMO, often as important as the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38400381/316310), an example is shown that redefines the name property of a function which is normally read-only. This seems to work just fine in v8.

```
// Apart from the added error so we can log a stack trace,
// this is unchanged from your example:
    const f = () => {
        return async (req, res, next) => {
            throw new Error("Intentionally cause an error to log the function's name.");
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            return next();
        }
    }
    const namedFunction = f();
```

When the function is called and its error is logged, you'd get a stack trace like this, as you saw in your profiler, the function has no name:

```
namedFunction().catch(console.log);

// Error: Intentionally cause an error to log the function's name.
//     at /tmp/namedfn.js:3:19
//     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/namedfn.js:9:5)
```

Rename as per the linked answer:

```
Object.defineProperty(namedFunction, 'name', {value: 'someFn'});
namedFunction().catch(console.log);

// Error: Intentionally cause an error to log the function's name.
//     at someFn (/tmp/namedfn.js:3:19)
//     at /tmp/namedfn.js:14:9
```

It is now named 'someFn' and should show up in your profiler as such.

---

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73209261/316310) is better / less hacky in cases where the source can be edited (OP doesn't have control over `f()`'s content according to a comment).

Comment: Didn't work you it still marks it as anonymous since in the end it's running in the context of the anonymous function